# unity Scriptable object not working in bulid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

hi I am new to unity and C# and I am making my first game. In it I have a Scriptable object named "sss".It contains values like coins,speed,jump power. It works fine in the editor but after I build it it wont work.what I mean by it wont work is after the player dies in the game depending on how long they live they will get a certain amount of coins when they go to the store they will see those coins displayed as a UI and they can spend them on things like speed and jump boost. this works in the editor but not in a build. Dose anybody know why this is? here is the code I have in my Scriptable object

```
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "data",menuName = "sss",order = 1)]
public class sss : ScriptableObject
{
   public float coins = 0f;
   public float speed = 10f;
   public float jump = -9.81f;
   public bool set = true;
   public int face = 1;
```

}

here is the code I use to display the coins float

```
coinstext.text = sss.coins.ToString();
```

and here is the whole store-manager script used to buy stuff

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net.Security;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class storemanager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public sss sss;
    public Text coinstext;
    public Slider sliders;
    public Slider sliderj;
    public int maxcap = 30;
    public int maxcapj = 500;
    public void Start()
    {


    coinstext.text = sss.coins.ToString();

    }

public void speedbuy()
{


    if (sss.coins >= 5 && sss.speed < maxcap)
    {
        sss.speed += 1;
        sss.buyspeed = true;
        sss.coins -= 5;
        sliders.value += 1;
        coinstext.text = sss.coins.ToString();
    }
}

public void jumpbuy()
{


    if (sss.coins >= 7 && sss.jump < maxcapj)
    {
        sss.jump += 10;
        sss.buyjump = true;
        sss.coins -= 7;
        sliderj.value += 10;
        coinstext.text = sss.coins.ToString();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While changes in [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) within the UnityEditor are persistent, they are **not persistent** in a **build**!

> When you use the Editor, you can save data to `ScriptableObjects` while editing and at run time because `ScriptableObjects` use the Editor namespace and Editor scripting. **In a deployed build, however, you can’t use `ScriptableObjects` to save data, but you can use the saved data from the `ScriptableObject` Assets that you set up during development.**

So after a build the data in the asset is kind of *baked* and you can change it at runtime but when restarting the app you will always re-load the data of the build.

---

You would need to store your data instead in a local file stored on the device itself e.g. using Json like

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
...

public class sss : ScriptableObject
{
    public float coins = 0f;
    public float speed = 10f;
    public float jump = -9.81f;
    public bool set = true;
    public int face = 1;

    private const string FILENAME = "sss.dat";

    public void SaveToFile()
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, FILENAME);

        if(!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Create(filePath);
        }
       
        var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
    }
        

    public void LoadDataFromFile()
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, FILENAME);

        if(!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Debug.LogWarning($"File \"{filePath}\" not found!", this);
            return;
        }

        var json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, this);
    }
}
```

And then in your manager script call the load and save methods e.g.

```
public class storemanager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public sss sss;

    public Text coinstext;
    public Slider sliders;
    public Slider sliderj;
    public int maxcap = 30;
    public int maxcapj = 500;

    public void Start()
    {
        sss.LoadFromFile();

        coinstext.text = sss.coins.ToString();
    }

    // Called when the application is going to quit
    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        sss.SaveToFile();
    }
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*